# Can I align a stroke to the inside of a shape with "Apply gradient across stroke"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient, stroke, appearance

I am trying to make a gradient going from the edge of a shape to its offset center, to make it look like letters that have been forged or carved in stone, in this style (but with 0° shadows):

[image]

Basically, I am trying to give letter O/**shape A**'s appearance to **shape B**, but without changing **Shape B**'s proportions/thickness. Shape A and shape B are the same object before I apply styles:

[image]

Unfortunately, *"Align stroke to inside"* in the **Align** panel is disabled for **shape A**, and I can't figure out why:

[image]

Scaling down doesn't work either, even with **"Scale strokes and Effects"** ticked / unticked.

I looked online, but [the only post on **Adobe's** forums that was remotely close to my problem](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/988096) had to do with shapes within groups. **Shape A** is not a part of any group:

[image]

These are the gradient options:

[image]

I would like the gradient to look like it does on **Shape A** but within the bounds of **Shape B**. I don't think **Offset Path** does what I want. I would prefer not to have to expand the gradient for this.

### ***Can I align this gradient stroke to another setting besides "Align to center"?***

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select align inside or outside if gradient is set to stroke. 
If i correctly undestood, shape A consists of 2 stroke - inside and outer and you apply gradient to outer stroke, but in this case you can use shape A with a single stroke, it's just a closed path and then apply gradient to this stroke with appropriate stroke width:  [image]

Also you can use Width Tool to achive some interesting results:

[image]

If you already have drawn letter forms and you don't want redraw them, gradient along stroke not a solution at all. 
I am afraid, but in case of 2d soft (like Illustrator) you can not just 'create a style and then apply to all forms', it's more for 3d soft: you create 3d objects, choose light source and get result.
Here you should deal with each object's surfaces separatly, keeping in mind light directions and manually recreating lighting/shading effects. You can use gradients applied to form, not stroke (especially several various gradients applied to the same form with various color blend modes) or use mesh, there are a lot of tutorials about this.

Comment: Please see me edit (paragraph before the second image). Ideally I would like to apply this style to all the letters and numbers of several whole alphabets without losing too much time tinkering.

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. That's how Illustrator gradient on stroke works.

**However**, you can cheat using the appearance panel:

Add the gradient stroke to your text and select `Path > Offset path` in the Appearance panel. Use a negative value to align the stroke to the inside of the text. You might have to tinker with the stroke width / offset value to get better results.

I also added a mask made with the text itself, to control part of the stroke "spilling out" of the shapes.

I don't believe it will be perfect, as you can see in my example below, it distorts a lot depending on the shape of the letter. On the top right corner there's an ellipse with the same gradient applied.

[image: gradient applied to text]